# Measure-Object result in variable incorrect inside ForEach-Object loop

Tags: powershell

In the following code I'm getting "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericObjectMeasureInfo.Minimum" for the result of the $oldest.Minimum while within the loop when running 
`$oldest = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum)`

After the loop $oldest.Minimum returns the correct value for the last object in the loop.
Additionally, if I just run `Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum`, I get the correct output within the loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

The Code:

```
$folders= @()
Get-Content -Path .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object{
echo "path is $_"
$oldest = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum)
echo "oldest folder is $oldest.Minimum"
$folders += "$_\$oldest.Minimum"
}
echo $oldest.Minimum
$minMin =($folders | Measure-Object -Minimum)
echo $minMin.Minimum
```

Result is:

```
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1
oldest folder is Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericObjectMeasureInfo.Minimum
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\2
oldest folder is Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericObjectMeasureInfo.Minimum
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\3
oldest folder is Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericObjectMeasureInfo.Minimum
2019-12-10
C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericObjectMeasureInfo.Minimum
```

Result with `Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum` in the loop, not storing to a varible.

```
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1


Count    : 5
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  : 2019-12-18
Property :

oldest folder is Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericObjectMeasureInfo.Minimum
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\2
Count    : 5
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  : 2019-12-18
Property :

oldest folder is Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericObjectMeasureInfo.Minimum
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\3
Count    : 5
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  : 2019-12-10
Property :
```

Expected output:

```
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1
oldest folder is 2019-12-18
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\2
oldest folder is 2019-12-18
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\3
oldest folder is 2019-12-10
2019-12-10
C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1\2019-12-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach loop, when you echo the statement "oldest folder is `$variable.property`", you are printing the `$variable` but not the `property`. Thats because `.property` is considered part of the string.

If you need to print the property of the variable within quoted string, you have to cover it with $() to make it an argument that needs to be evaluated. Following this solve the issue.

```
Get-Content -Path .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object{
  echo "path is $_"
  $oldest = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum)
  echo "oldest folder is $($oldest.Minimum)"
  $folders += "$_\$($oldest.Minimum)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.